# Datatable dom l filter has no label

Tags: datatables

I'm using a theme, and somehow giving the `dom` option of `l` only shows the dropdown without the label.

<`Show` [dropdown here] `entries`>

How do I get the label to show, and how to customise the labels?

Example here with the label:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eJTN86XnfeDKSBUfaHlJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit

The `sLengthMenu` is overriding the default text for the filter list.
Just had to remove it.

```
oLanguage: {
  "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_"
}
```